# Restricting SpinButtons to specific Min and Max values VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to restrict user to select value between a limit using SpinButton in VBA but its not working for me
Here is what I have tried

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    decimalSpin_Button.Min = 0
    decimalSpin_Button.Max = 5
End Sub


Private Sub decimalSpin_Button_Change()

decimalPlaces_Value.Text = decimalSpin_Button.Value
End Sub
Private Sub decimalSpin_Button_SpinDown()

decimalPlaces_Value.Text = decimalPlaces_Value.Text - 1


End Sub

Private Sub decimalSpin_Button_SpinUp()
decimalPlaces_Value.Text = val(decimalPlaces_Value.Text) + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `_SpinDown()` and `_SpinUp()` This will do what you want

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    decimalSpin_Button.Min = 0
    decimalSpin_Button.Max = 5
End Sub

Private Sub decimalSpin_Button_Change()
    decimalPlaces_Value.Text = decimalSpin_Button.Value
End Sub
```